# Is there any paper about the distribution of difference of log-normal variable?

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, estimators, approximation, ratio

I am working on the problem relating to the difference of log-normal distribution. I have found several papers about this topic, however, none of them gives me the answer I want. 
More specifically, the variable I look at is the ratio of two difference of log-normal variables, i.e., 
$$\frac{e^{x_1}-e^{y_1}}{e^{x_2}-e^{y_2}}$$
 where $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ are normal distributed; $x_1, x_2$ are correlated, and $y_1, y_2$ are correlated.

Comment: I expect there's a very good reason why you're having trouble finding that exact case. Is there any reason you really need that in closed form?

Comment: yes, I need the exact form of the distribution or an approximation. I want to examine the properties of this ratio, which is an important estimator in my current project. I have worked out the estimator with normal distribution which is relatively easy.

Comment: It's not clear why you need an algebraic formula to "examine properties"; what can you find out that you couldn't find out from simulation?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152850/difference-of-two-i-i-d-lognormal-random-variables/176374#176374

Comment: Also see (maybe a duplicate):  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178081/distribution-of-ratio-of-2-points-drawn-from-normal-distribution/306073#306073