# Tolerance Interval from the posterior predictive distribution of a ratio of two Normal distributions

Tags: bayesian, ratio, tolerance-interval

I am trying to calculate a Beta-Gamma Tolerance Interval from the Posterior Predictive Distribution of a log(ratio) of two normal (no close form available).

In the minimal R code below, assume `x1` and `x2` are actually posterior distributions generated from an MCMC sampler. I am trying to get a tolerance interval for `x3`. Is this possible?

```
x1 = rnorm(1e5, 5, 1)
x2 = rnorm(1e5, 5, 1)
x3 = log(x1/x2)
```

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306073/919 gives references to closed form expressions for the Normal ratio distribution.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. Although the close form does not give us the tolerance interval, does it?